# The lambda function does not work with the scipy integral in python

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, quad

I have the code structure below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

t = np.linspace(0, .85, 5)
s = np.ones_like(t)
f = lambda t, s: t - s
Int = integrate.quad(f, 1, 2)
Int
```

Even if I change the `s` and the bounds in `(f, 1, 2)`, I received the error below. I compared this to the information provided by the Scipy and Lambda references. Still, I cannot see how I can solve this error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-087d4b0d784a> in <module>
      4 s = np.ones_like(t)
      5 f = lambda t, s: t - s
----> 6 Int = integrate.quad(f, 1, 2)
      7 Int

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    461     if points is None:
    462         if infbounds == 0:
--> 463             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    464         else:
    465             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

**EDIT:** I'm trying to code the following integral, but in this post I tried to express it more simply.
[integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCvlq.jpg)

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: `quad` integrates a function of one variable.  You defined a function of 2.  Make sure your function matches the `quad` documentation.

Comment: @hpaulj Actually I need a `scipy` integration package to integrate a function of two variable (these are `numpy` arrays) and it should be for numerical calculation not for symbolic.

Comment: @hpaulj  I guess `integrate.simpson(y, x)` seems like a correct choice.

Comment: In your `f` definition, `t` and `s` are local variables; they aren't the `t` and `s` arrays you defined earlier.   What are you trying to 'integrate'?  The 'area' under the line plotting 's'` against 't'?  For 's' all 1s, this would be the rectangle area `(2-1)*1=2`

Comment: @hpaulj I made an edit and added what I tried to integrate into the link. Yes, you are definitely right, they are not arrays. I made a mistake to say this. And I just tried to see the effect of `s`, but I think `s` should be just a variable. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that will only resolve the mentioned problem:

```py
s = np.ones_like(t)
f = lambda t, s: t - s
```

Here, the lambda's `s` doesn't capture the variable `s` you declared before, it is just a second parameter that you will need to fill in at some point. So `.quad` function expect either a function with one parameter, or if it has more than one, expect the rest of the arguments to be filled in the `.quad`'s `args` parameter. (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)

This is why the error tells you
`missing 1 required positional argument: 's'`

If you want to capture a previously declared variable you don't need to specify another parameter, so your lambda should be:

```py
f = lambda t: t - s
```

With this, you don't need to fill in additional arguments in the `args` parameter and you will have no error about the number of arguments

If you wanted to capture the `t` variable from before, you need to remove the parameter in the lambda too but then you'll end up with a lambda that takes 0 arguments, and .quad takes a lambda/function that takes at least one parameter

Comment: When I removed the `s`in lambda, it gives another error as `only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

Comment: I've only answered your question to why you get this specific error. You actually have to remove both parameters on the lambda if you want to use the `t` and `s` that are previously declared, as @hpaulj said.